# unable to display ValidationResult in handlebar views

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js

I want to validate a form using npm's validator and display the errors into my handlebar views.

### JS code

```
  router.post('/place-order',

  [
    //pincode must be 5 digits long
    body('pincode').isLength({ min: 5 }),
    //mobile number must be in 10 digits long
    body('mobile').isLength({ min: 10 })
  ],

  async (req, res) => {

    const errors = validationResult(req);
    let e = errors.array();
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      res.render('/place-order', { e })
    }
```

This is what I'm getting after console.log(errors)

### Array of errors (i.e., let e = errors.array() in the above code)

```
[
  {
    value: '1',
    msg: 'Invalid value',
    param: 'pincode',
    location: 'body'
  },
  {
    value: '2',
    msg: 'Invalid value',
    param: 'mobile',
    location: 'body'
  }
]
```

### Handlebar's code

```
{{#each e}}
<h1>{{this.msg}}</h1>
{{/each}}
```

When I run this code, server responding with a status of 500 error and it's
not prompting the error to the screen.